# “Could not find a part of the path” asmx web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a web service web method that accepts an image (as a byte[] array).

```
[WebMethod]
        public string SaveImage(byte[] fs, string fileName)
        {
            string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "/Images/" + fileName;

            try
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fs);
                //Server.MapPath("~/Images/")
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew);

                ms.WriteTo(stream); 
                ms.Close();
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose(); 

                return "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message.ToString() +
                        "\n" +
                        DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() +
                        "---" +
                        DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() +
                        "\n" +
                        "-----------------------------";
                Logger.WriteLog(msg);

                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

I have added correct permissions to the folder, but whatever I try i get the same error,

> “Could not find a part of the path c:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\Images”

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Does the c:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\Images folder exist?

Comment: not sure though but i faced a similar issue. What i did was used a generic handler for this particular request where i was to handle file uploading. you can try the same thing

Comment: yes the folder exists.

Comment: Manish please elaborate on your solution.

Comment: Does the filename exists too ? I Faced the same issue in the past, I resolved it by changing `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` by `HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath`

Comment: Nope the filename doesnt exist. it is unique, in that folder.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/uploading-files-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net1 Have a look at this.

Comment: I am not sure this will help with what i need. The web service is consumed from an android app. I upload a image file from the device to the service

Comment: I think it is a permission issue, i added the correct permissions to that folder but same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after testing a bit there was an issue saving data that came from another platform(android) so i converted the image to a base64 string. And that i converted to an image and successfully saved to the folder.